Why does this vim.keymap.set not work?
I was trying to setup coc.nvim, and copied their example config. Then I started checking if the remaps are working, and found a problem with this line:
local keyset = vim.keymap.set
local opts = { silent = true, noremap = true, expr = true, replace_keycodes = false }
-- ...
keyset("i", "<cr>", [[coc#pum#visible() ? coc#pum#confirm() : "\<C-g>u\<CR>\<c-r>=coc#on_enter()\<CR>"]], opts)

Running :verbose imap <cr> prints this:
i  <CR>        * <Lua 45: ~/.local/share/nvim/lazy/nvim-cmp/lua/cmp/utils/keymap.lua:127>
                 cmp.utils.keymap.set_map
    Last set from Lua (run Nvim with -V1 for more details)

At first I thought that cmp just overrides the mapping, but even if I run the remap command manually, after everything has loaded, it still doesn't take effect. Why is that?
Note: I'm new to Neovim and don't fully understand the syntax here. I just blindly copied the command from the readme.

Could you tell us what version of Neovim you are using? I would like to verify that it support replace_keycode=false

@VivianDeSmedt
NVIM v0.10.1
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.1713484068
Run "nvim -V1 -v" for more info

I have verified replace_keycodes is supported by Neovim 0.10.

I'm wondering if your code is executed. If you put it in a .lua file and executed with the :%so command or the :so % command, does it provide your the correct behavior (I noticed that the verbose imap <CR> on Neovim doesn't provide the last version of the mapping (looks like a bug). So to verify that your mapping is working you have to test the functionality.

"blindly copied from the README"—now is a good time to learn not to do that :)

@VivianDeSmedt verbose imap <cr> was indeed not working properly. I tried to use the mapping, and it worked. Though I remember the mapping was not working initially; at some point during my fiddling, it got fixed, but I'm not sure when.

Thanks forbthe feedback! The behavior is indeed odd. Maybe should we reported in Neovim as a bug.

nvim-cmp and coc.nvim are two LSP bridges.
I believe you can't have both installed at the same time.
I observed that nvim-cmp is actually resetting buffer mapping for Tab in insert mode each time you switch to insert mode. That is why whatever you configure for coc.nvim it is overridden when you switch to insert mode by nvim-cmp.
I suppose the solution is to disable nvim-cmp or chose not to use coc.nvim.

Didn't help.. I had also tried running :lua vim.keymap.set(<all the params>) to no avail. Also, the other commands from their config that are setup the exact same way still work somehow.

Did you saw the new answer I have provided? Does it make sense to you?

Yeah, I thought I needed CoC for flutter, but then I found an LSP tool for it, so I removed CoC, and stayed with LSP.
